# Replace variables in a list dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list with some variables that I wanted to replace:

```
intros = [
"Hi, my name is {name} and I'm {age}",
"I'm {age} years old",
"My name is {name} and I live in {city}"
]
```

I know that in that list the variables `name`, `age` and `city` exist. What I don't know is if all of them exist in each element or some of them might be missing. I tried to create a generic way of doing that but it's not working as expected.

```
def build_intros(introductions, *args):
    formatted_intros = []

    for arg in args:
        for intro in intros:
            vars_to_replace = list(set(re.findall("\{([^}]+)\}", intro)))
            for var_to_replace in vars_to_replace:
                intro = intro.replace("{" + var_to_replace + "}", arg)
                formatted_intros.append(intro)

name = "John"
age = "22"
city = "Texas"

build_intros(introductions, name, age, city)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "John"
age = "22"
city = "Texas"

intros = [
f"Hi, my name is {name} and I'm {age}",
f"I'm {age} years old",
f"My name is {name} and I live in {city}"
]

print(intros)
```

This will work.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

This link will explain how we use f- strings

Comment: Thanks @Divyessh for the reply. How could I do this in a function? Like I would pass the config to the function and it would return the formatted config?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another example

```
intros = [
"Hi, my name is {name} and I'm {age}",
"I'm {age} years old",
"My name is {name} and I live in {city}"
]

for i in intros:
    print(i.format(name = "ads", age="49", city="New York"))
```